# For Loop output issue

Tags: c++

[should be getting the output on the picture**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAAyy.png)A tax table shows three columns: an annual salary, the tax rate, and the tax amount to pay. The program below shows most of the code needed to calculate a tax table

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
enter code here

int main() {
int INCOME_INCREMENT        = 5000;
int    annualSalary         = 0;
double taxRate              = 0.0;
int    taxToPay             = 0;
int    startingAnnualSalary = 40000;  40000
int    endingAnnualSalary   = 60000;  60000

cout << "Enter first annual salary for the table: " << endl;
cin >> startingAnnualSalary;
cout << "Enter last annual salary for the table: " << endl;
cin >> endingAnnualSalary;
cout << "Enter the increment for the table: " << endl;
cin >> INCOME_INCREMENT;





for (int i = 0 ; i < 9 ; i++ ){


// Determine the tax rate from the annual salary
if (annualSalary <= 0) {
     taxRate = 0.0;
  }
else if (annualSalary <= 20000) {
     taxRate = 0.10;   // 0.10 is 10% written as a decimal
  }
else if (annualSalary <= 50000) {
     taxRate = 0.20;
  }
else if (annualSalary <= 100000) {
     taxRate = 0.30;
  }
else {
     taxRate = 0.40;
  }

taxToPay = static_cast<int>(annualSalary  -taxToPay * taxRate);   //  Truncate tax to an integer amount
cout << "Annual salary: " << annualSalary <<
          "\tTax rate: " << taxRate <<
          "\tTax to pay: " << taxToPay << endl;

// FIXME: Be sure to include the closing brace for the for loop
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Uhhm, and, whats your question? What happens? What should happen (without following external links)? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and concrete question...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: Alter the program to ask the user for the increment to use in addition to the starting and ending annual salaries.
Run the program again using an increment of 2500. Are the entries for 40000, 45000, 50000, 55000 and 60000 the same as before

Comment: Output : `Annual salary: 0 Tax rate: 0 Tax to pay: 0` - I would look for a better job (or update `annualSalary`with the input)

Comment: i just don't know how to get the expected output. my output and the expected output is in the picture i attached

Answer (score 0):

You don't assign values to `annualSalary` from the input.

You should try like:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int INCOME_INCREMENT        = 5000;
    int    annualSalary         = 0;
    double taxRate              = 0.0;
    int    taxToPay             = 0;
    int    startingAnnualSalary = 40000;  //40000  <-- comment out
    int    endingAnnualSalary   = 60000;  //60000  <-- comment out

    cout << "Enter first annual salary for the table: " << endl;
    cin >> startingAnnualSalary;
    cout << "Enter last annual salary for the table: " << endl;
    cin >> endingAnnualSalary;
    cout << "Enter the increment for the table: " << endl;
    cin >> INCOME_INCREMENT;


    annualSalary = startingAnnualSalary;  // Set the start value


    while(annualSalary <= endingAnnualSalary ){  // Loop until reaching end value 
        // Determine the tax rate from the annual salary
        if (annualSalary <= 0) {
             taxRate = 0.0;
        }
        else if (annualSalary <= 20000) {
             taxRate = 0.10;   // 0.10 is 10% written as a decimal
        }
        else if (annualSalary <= 50000) {
            taxRate = 0.20;
        }
        else if (annualSalary <= 100000) {
            taxRate = 0.30;
        }
        else {
            taxRate = 0.40;
        }

        taxToPay = static_cast<int>(annualSalary * taxRate + 0.5);   //  Correct calculation
                                                                     // Add 0.5 for correct rounding
        cout << "Annual salary: " << annualSalary <<
                  "\tTax rate: " << taxRate <<
                  "\tTax to pay: " << taxToPay << endl;

        annualSalary +=  INCOME_INCREMENT;  // Update annualSalary for next loop
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Annual salary: 40000    Tax rate: 0.2   Tax to pay: 8000
Annual salary: 42500    Tax rate: 0.2   Tax to pay: 8500
Annual salary: 45000    Tax rate: 0.2   Tax to pay: 9000
Annual salary: 47500    Tax rate: 0.2   Tax to pay: 9500
Annual salary: 50000    Tax rate: 0.2   Tax to pay: 10000
Annual salary: 52500    Tax rate: 0.3   Tax to pay: 15750
Annual salary: 55000    Tax rate: 0.3   Tax to pay: 16500
Annual salary: 57500    Tax rate: 0.3   Tax to pay: 17250
Annual salary: 60000    Tax rate: 0.3   Tax to pay: 18000
```

A pretty bad tax system! If paid 50.000 you'll end up with more money than you get if paid 52.500 :-)

Comment: somehow i'm short one annual salary output at the end 
Annual salary: 40000 Tax rate: 0.2 Tax to pay: 8000
Annual salary: 42500 Tax rate: 0.2 Tax to pay: 8500
Annual salary: 45000 Tax rate: 0.2 Tax to pay: 9000
Annual salary: 47500 Tax rate: 0.2 Tax to pay: 9500
Annual salary: 50000 Tax rate: 0.2 Tax to pay: 10000
Annual salary: 52500 Tax rate: 0.3 Tax to pay: 15750
Annual salary: 55000 Tax rate: 0.3 Tax to pay: 16500
Annual salary: 57500 Tax rate: 0.3 Tax to pay: 1